# How can I set a value for a LinkedItem?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I want to do the following:

```
electronicSignatureModel.createdBy.Id = DbContext.CurrentUser.CreatedById;
```

where electronicSignatureModel.createdBy.Id = DbContext.CurrentUser.CreatedById; is a long? and DbContext.CurrentUser.CreatedById is a long?. When I try to do this I get a NullReferenceException. DbContext.CurrentUser.CreatedById has a value, so I think it has to do with electronicSignatureModel.createdBy.Id. electronicSignatureModel.createdBy is a LinkedItem and is null. How can I fill this LinkedItem, so that it is not null?

The LinkedItem looks as follows:

```
#if SCRIPTSHARP
    [Imported]
    [IgnoreNamespace]
    [ScriptName("Object")]
#endif
    public class LinkedItem : BaseModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// entity that represents the item
        /// </summary>

#if SCRIPTSHARP
        [PreserveCase]
#endif
        public string Entity;

        /// <summary>
        /// name of the item
        /// </summary>
#if SCRIPTSHARP
        [PreserveCase]
#endif
        public string Name;

        /// <summary>
        /// id of the item
        /// </summary>
#if SCRIPTSHARP
        [PreserveCase]
#endif
        public long? Id;





    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `electronicSignatureModel`? How does that type look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is `null`, it means it has no value. And you can't modify properties of nothing. If you want to set the `Id` of `createdBy`, you first have to set `createdBy` to some non-`null` value.

How to do that depends on how does the type of `electronicSignatureModel`, but assuming it's a property with accessible setter (or a public field, but you should avoid those), you can do for example something like:

```
var createdBy = new LinkedItem();
createdBy.Id = DbContext.CurrentUser.CreatedById;
electronicSignatureModel.createdBy = createdBy;
```

Or alternatively, using [object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
electronicSignatureModel.createdBy =
    new LinkedItem { Id = DbContext.CurrentUser.CreatedById };
```

Comment: got it to work, didn't use the model so had to do var createdBy = new test.Web.Framework.Models.LinkedItem(); instead. Thanks.